# join n rows by column into single row dataframe pandas

Tags: pandas

I have

```
pd.DataFrame({'col1':['23','34'], 'col2':[21324,345436]})
```

I want

```
pd.DataFrame({'col1':['[23,34]'], 'col2':['[21324,345436]']})
```

I have dataframe with many rows. I would like to join all values into a single list un the same column header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html)/[`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with a custom function to convert to list then string:

```
df.agg(lambda x: [str(list(x))])

# or
df.apply(lambda x: [str(list(x))])
```

Output:

```
           col1             col2
0  ['23', '34']  [21324, 345436]
```